# How do I get web browser element's css style?

Tags: c#, html, css, browser

I have a page like the below in my web browser that I want to get the `style` atributte value. I tried:

```
 HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("foo");
            MessageBox.Show(ele.GetAttribute("style"));
```

but it output:

```
System.__ComObject
```

Why does it output a `System.__ComObject` type and how do I handle it?

**HTML page:**

```
<div id="foo" style="display:block;">
a
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ele.Style
```

Will help.

```
ele.GetAttribute("Style")
```

won't work because returns string, so it can't say more than that is an object, while `ele.Style` returns `CssStyleCollection`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var e = document.getElementById('foo');
var css = window.getComputedStyle(e,null).getPropertyValue("display");
alert(css);
```

Comment: This will be very useful too. Thansk!